# Determine size of the area where a component can potentially expand

Tags: java, swing, resize, layout-manager, miglayout

Is there a way to determine the area a component could have for itself in a container?

I'm using [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/). Say I have two components: a `JPanel` and a `JSlider`, that are added in a container. The JSlider is docked south of the container, and grows/shrinks horizontally when the container is resized. The JPanel has some initial size, say, 100x100. In this scenario, the JPanel could have for itself all the area the container has, except for the area that the JSlider occupies. So if the container is 400x400, the JPanel *could* have a size of 400x384, if the slider had a height of 16, and if it expanded fully.

Anyway, If I call `panel.getSize()`, I get 100x100, as I should. I want to know if there is a way to get the size of the area where the component *could* expand. So in this case, I would like to do something that gets me a dimension of 400x384.

---

Illustration:

[image]

Here the black outline marks the *container*, white indicates unused space, red marks the *slider* and blue marks the component whose available space I'm trying to determine.

Comment: Why do you need to know the available space? Your custom component should ask for all the space it needs and let the layout manager allocate the space.

Comment: @camickr I'm resizing the jpanel manually to maintain aspect ratio.

Comment: @camickr But that's not the point of this question. I want to know in any case if what I'm asking is possible.

Comment: Yes it is the point, because many times people implement a complicated solution when an easier approach to the problem is available. But first we need to know the exact requirement and reasons for the requirement, not just your attempted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your layout.

For example I would use a BorderLayout. Then you add your red panel to the south and another panel to the "CENTER" of the BorderLayout. This other panel will now contain all the available space available in the frame.

Then you add your blue panel to the panel you just added to the center. Now you can just use:

```
blue.getParent().getSize();
```

to determine the space available.

In other words don't always try to solve layout problems with a single layout manager.

Comment: This is what I originally had in mind. Seemed a bit hackish at the time, but since you gave me the same solution, I think I'll go with it. However, I don't see the point in using borderlayout over miglayout; I can easily do this with miglayout as well.